# How do I capture every compilation in Java?

Tags: java

I am working on a research on programmer problem solving strategies. I would like to capture every compilation done by the programmer in Java, i.e. every time the programmer compiles his program, a copy of the program is stored somewhere. I will be using this compilation history for deeper analysis on my research.

I have read about BlueJ but I was discouraged using this. I intend to let the programmers use JCreator as IDE or javac on command line for the study.

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: Use an IDE that supports version control.

Comment: Why do you want to use the compilation result? Wouldn't the source code be of more use?

Comment: I'm not certain this is the right place for your question. Broadly speaking no code means not on topic, but if you essentially overroad the javac command with a bash script that does your save and then calls the actual compiler that might work.

Comment: Many modern IDEs compile incrementally as you type.  I can go days without explicitly compiling my programs.

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is not when the user _compiles_ his program but when he _runs_ it to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Intercepting compilation requests can be difficult, or even impossible with some IDEs. It also limits what tools the programmer can use, and programmers don't usually like that.

A better way to go about this might be to use a [filesystem monitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) to watch for when the user saves their code, which will also roughly correspond to what you are looking for.

Comment: Even then, with some IDEs such as IntelliJ, the user doesn't explicitly save his/her code; the IDE saves it automatically all the time.

Comment: In that case, the filesystem will still be modified so the OP can get a sense for how the file evolved over time